# Run a forloop for a variable times

Tags: loops, variable

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=3in, multi={my}, crop, ignorerest=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{polyglossia, lipsum, forloop}
\usepackage[most, magazine]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, calc}

\newcounter{loopcntr}
\newcommand{\rpt}[2][1]{%
  \forloop{loopcntr}{1}{\value{loopcntr}<#1}{#2}}

\tcbset{
  breakable,
  break at=3 in,
  reset box array,
  store to box array
}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
  enhanced,
  title=#2,#1}

\newcommand{\xxbody}{%
  \lipsum[1-2]%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{Heading}

  \xxbody{}

\end{mybox}%

\boxarraygetsize{\mysize}

% \rpt[\mysize]{
\rpt[10]{
\begin{my}%
  \useboxarray{\theloopcntr}%
\end{my}%
}

\end{document}
```

If I give a specific count to the `\rpt` macro, it works. But produces several blank pages at the end.

To avoid this, if I use `\mysize` macro (like in the commented line), it produces an 'Undefined control sequence' error.

What could be the problem? How do I set this right?

Comment: how have you defined  `\forloop` or `\useboxarray` ? please post small but complete test document that shows the issue, not fragments

Comment: `\forloop` is from the `forloop` package and this is easy. But we cannot know what `\useboxarray`, `my` and `\mysize` are. I see that `\useboxarray` is defined by `tcolorbox`, but we *really* need something more to understand what's going on.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have added the MWE. Apologies, could have added it earlier.

Comment: @egreg I have added the MWE. Apologies, could have added it earlier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The loop macro you are using apparently generates some construct in which the macros are not defined. That could probably be fixed but the simplest solution starting from here is to expand `\mysize` before the call, you get no error from

```
\expandafter\rpt\expandafter[\mysize]{
```

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick.

Comment: I think the cause is `standalone` with setting `multi={my}` typesets every `my` env in a separate group, which makes the local assignment to `\mysize` before any `my` env lost. Evidence: OP's example compiles with `article` document class and a dummy `my` env definition.